# Hide and show lists and sublists

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

First of all, I have a HTML document which contains lists like this :

```
<ul class="item">
    <li> Item 1
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Item 2 
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li> Item 3 
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to write some `Javascript` code that when I click on a item from the list item, it shows its sub-items.  If I click on another item from the item list, all the displayed subitems should be hidden and only the one I have pressed to be displayed.

So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.subitem').each(function()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('.item').live("click",function(){
        $(this).next(".subitem").show();
    });
});
```

but it does not even display the hidden subitem.  Could you help me, please?

Comment: Can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Why not use one of the many plugins out there that already do just this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this.

```
$(function () {
    var $subitem = $(".subitem");

    $('.item').on("click", "li", function () {
        /* Hide all .subitem */
        $subitem.hide();
        /* Show children .subitem */
        $(this).children(".subitem").show();
    });
});
```

Instead of using JavaScript to hide all the `.subitem` at initialization, you can use CSS.

```
.subitem {
    display: none;
}
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ktWUb/)

Comment: thank you for the answer but the main item does not toggle. I mean the children is not visible because of the item.

Comment: @StackOverfolow, say again? What is not visible?

Comment: I mean when the subitem menu is displayed , the next item after the one was clicked it is not moving , it does not aligh to the end of the submenu, instead the submenu is displayed under the item.

Comment: @StackOverfolow, you mean like it's shown now? Check the update. If I understand correctly you have a special CSS styling for the `<ul>` and `<li>`?

Comment: @StackOverfolow, update your answer. Even though technically, the question has been answered. But, it seems you are unable to make it work with your current CSS styles

Comment: yes it was answered. Could you provide me some reasons why it might not work with my css styles ?

Comment: @StackOverfolow, you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with HTML, CSS and JS all on it.

Comment: thank you for your support , i have updated the jsfiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/74Jmr/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.item').on('click','li', function(){
   $(this).children(".subitem").show()
   .end().siblings().find('.subitem').hide();
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aMWMu/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.subitem').hide();

$('.item > li').on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().find(li .subitem).hide()
    $(this).find(".subitem").show();
});
```